# Set cookies with JavaScript. Not work on safari(MacOS & iOS)

Tags: javascript, safari

I have a JavaScript on my homepage to set a cookies on any browser. It is working on Chrome. However, it is not work on Safari.

I have enabled the developer mode on Safari, and there is no any error.

Here is my JavaScript

```
<script>
var cookieName = "tempid";
var cookieValue = "xxxxx";
var expirationTime = 2592000;
expirationTime = expirationTime * 1000;
var date = new Date();
var dateTimeNow = date.getTime();
date.setTime(dateTimeNow + expirationTime);
var expirationTime = date.toUTCString();
document.cookie = cookieName+"="+cookieValue+";
expires="+expirationTime+"; path=/; domain=." +
location.hostname.replace(/^www\./i, ""); 
</script>
```

Is there any code here which is not supported by Safari? or what is the right method to set cookies on Safari with JavaScript?

Comment: which version of safari?

Comment: The line where you set the cookie has a newline in the middle of a string; is that really what your code looks like?

Comment: `document.cookie = cookieName+"="+cookieValue+";
expires="` <--- hmm